# How do I create a JSONArray from this string?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, gson

I have the following json string:

```
[{"username":"ddd","status":"Inactive"},{"username":"eee","status":"Inactive"}]
```

Which I created using `Gson` to format the Json string from a `List<Map<String, Object>> userList...`:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(userList);
```

How can I now create a JSONArray so I can iterate over it and extract the values in each object?

Comment: If you are using Gson, why would you *want* a `JSONArray`? I would use Gson to parse that back into `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Comment: Isn't it already a JSONArray?

Comment: @mjp66 no at the moment its just a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to convert a JSON string to a JSONArray (provided the string is valid) is like so, using your string `jsonString` as the parameter:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

And then you can pick off the individual objects in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String username = object.getString("username");
    String status = object.getString("status");
}
```

Comment: What's the whole package name for JSONArray, damn?

Answer (score 3):

If `jsonString` is your string and you like to convert it back to a `List<Map<String, Object>>` try with

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>() { }.getType();
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```